# Magento 1.9 Site onto Github

Tags: magento, github, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

This is probably a really stupid question. Is there a way to get a magento 1.9 site which is hosted on a godaddy server (idk why they would do such a thing), into a github so that these people can develop properly? Im not too family with a cms on a github. What happens if they update content within the cms by logging into it? etc. If anyone has any sort of resources I can use, i can't seem to find any. More of an application developer myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes. There's a good [gist](https://gist.github.com/Nilpo/8ed5e44be00d6cf21f22) explaining how to use git to manage a live site.

Longer answer: Yes. You'll need to init a repo on the site as it is, i.e. your public_html or htdocs directory. You can the push the content of this repo into a bare repo on Github, and manage sharing/access to the repo therein. After your devs have made changes and you're ready to put them into production, you'd `git pull` from the github site to bring over the changes. There's a LOT to git, and it's not simple, but there are good resources out there available by googling.

> What happens if they update content within the cms by logging into it?

CMS content lives within the database. That content doesn't get pushed into github, unless you make dumps of the database that you keep in the repo. *BAD IDEA!*